# where is the openssl.so file located in the system?

Tags: php-extension, php-openssl

Working on a linux system.
openssl extension is enabled as it shows in phpinfo(). 
but openssl.so file nowhere in the system. running the command :"php -v" gives the following error "unale to load dynamic library- usr/lib/php/20131226/openssl.so -no such file or directory"

I am a naive. This might be a very stupid ques. but I shall be grateful for any help.